# How can I get array values from key in json file with python?

Tags: python, json

Here is my JSON file:

`{"name": "Nghia", "name2": ["Bao", "Tam"]}`

My Python code:

```
file = open(jsonfile, 'r')
data = json.load(file)
key = list(data.keys())
value = list(data.values())
print(key[value.index('Nghia')])
```

Output: `name`

But the issue is I can't use `key[value.index('Bao')]` or `key[value.index('Tam')]` to get `name2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to match a string to a list, which will of course not match. If you must keep the structure of your data, you need to explicitly check for both strings matching or the list containing the string. For example:

```
data = {"name": "Nghia", "name2": ["Bao", "Tam"]}

search_term = "Bao"

for k, v in data.items():
  if v == search_term or search_term in v:
    print("Found in " + k)
  else :
    print("Not found in " + k)
```

which will output

```
Not found in name
Found in name2
```

Comment: Hi sir, I can't search some special strings/characters like "0.1.2.3". How can I make it possible?
My JSON is {"a": "0.1.2.3", "b": "c"}

Comment: @HiImNghia I do not know what you mean. "0.1.2.3" is a normal string like any other, and my code above works for it just fine.

Comment: I added a : 0.1.2.3 to my json file and changed search_term to "0.1.2.3", then I used your code but it printed Not found

Comment: `a : 0.1.2.3` is valid in neither JSON nor Python. Once again, my code works just fine for strings like "0.1.2.3" assuming your data has valid strings: https://repl.it/repls/LemonchiffonJuniorProtocols.

Comment: thanks! I got it to work now. Can I ask you an off-topic question about remove a value like "Nghia" or "Tam"?

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the index() method finds the given element in a list and returns its position.

So here,

```py
key = list(data.keys()) // ['name', 'name2']
value = list(data.values()) // ['Nghia', ['Bao', 'Tam']]
```

Now this code

```py
print(key[value.index('Nghia')])
```

finds the element from this list ['Nghia', ['Bao', 'Tam']] and returns the index of that element and print it.

So above you can see in the second element of the list ['Nghia', ['Bao', 'Tam']], we have an array as element ['Bao', 'Tam']

So in order to find the the index of that element in the value list, you have to use this

```py
print(key[value.index(['Bao', 'Tam'])])
```

here is the function which returns the index of an element if the element in the list is an array or string

Function takes two arguments value and item,
value is a List
item is the element of list which index needs to be find

Function returns -1 if its not found any item in the list

```
def findIndex(value,item):
    for elementIndex in range(0, len(value)):
        if type(value[elementIndex]) is list:
            for itemElemIndex in range(0 ,len(value[elementIndex])):
                if value[elementIndex][itemElemIndex] == item:
                    return elementIndex    
        else:
            if value[elementIndex] == item:
                return elementIndex
    return -1
```

```
print(key[findIndex(value,"Tam")])
```

Comment: Is there any way to get `name2` with **Bao** or **Tam**? Difference code with be accepted